# Creating Multiple Dynamic Dependent Dropdowns that are all dependent on eachother

Tags: forms, ajax

So my example can be broken down like
Country = Dropdown
State = Dropdown
City = Dropdown
County = Dropdown

I want, if I select United States in the Country Dropdown, I get the states in the US, if I select the states, I get the City's in that State etc.

This is what I want to do, but so far I can get to selecting the Country then the State, but not anywhere else.

(My Code isn't using the Country and States as variables, it was just an example for what I'm trying to do functionality wise)

```
function firstmodule_menu() {
  $items['firstmodule/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('My first Drupal form'),
    'page callback' => 'firstmodule_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My first Drupal form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function firstmodule_permission(){
    return array(
    'access firstmodule content' => array(
        'title' => t('Accesss Content for the FirstModule module'),
        )
    );
}

 function firstmodule_Permissions() {
     $items = array();
     $items['current_posts'] = array(
        'title' => 'First Module Permissions',
        'page callback' => 'firstmodule_form',
        'access arguments' => array('access current_posts content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK_ITEM, 
    );
    return $items;

}

function firstmodule_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('firstmodule_form1');
}


function firstmodule_form1($form,$form_state) {


$options_first = FirstDropdownOptions();
$options_second = SecondDropdownOptions();
$options_third = ThirdDropdownOptions();
$selected =  isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first']:key($options_first);
$selected1 = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second']:key($options_second);
$selected2 = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_third']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_third']:key($options_third);

$form['dropdown_first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Instrument Type',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#default_value' => $selected,

    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
    ),
);

$form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Instruments'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => SecondDropdownOptions($selected1),
    '#default_value' => $selected,

    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'dropdown-third-replace',
    ),
);


$form['dropdown_third'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Instrument Type',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-third-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => ThirdDropdownOptions($selected2),
    '#default_value' => $selected,

    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'dropdown-fourth-replace',
    ),
);

$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit'),
);


return $form;
```

}

```
function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
    if(isset($form_state['value']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['value']['dropdown_first']:key($options_first)){
        return $form['dropdown_first'];
    }
    else{
        return $form['dropdown_second'];
    }
}


function FirstDropdownOptions() {
  return drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('City'),
      t('StateName'),
      t('PropertyName'),
      t('Address'),
    )
  );
}

function SecondDropdownOptions($key = '') {
    $selCity = db_query('SELECT city FROM {site_list}')->fetchCol();
  $options = array(
    t('City') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        $selCity,
      )
    ),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
  return $form;
}


function ThirdDropdownOptions($key = '') {
    $selStateName = db_query('SELECT customer FROM {site_list}')->fetchCol();
  $options = array(
    t('StateName') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        $selStateName,
      )
    ),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
  return $form;
}

function firstmodule_form1_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```